# bash, getting ' characters inside printf statements

Tags: bash, printf, escaping, echo

I find it hard to nest `printf` statements inside aliases. I have a number of help topics that I want to have available (just little collections of helpful tips for when I forget syntax). I have found out that `printf` requires `\` to be escaped as `\\` and `%` to be escaped as `%%`. However, my problem is more to do with `'` and `"`

```
alias helpx='printf "A note about 'vim'.\n"'
=> A note about vim.   # The ' are ignored.

alias helpx="printf 'A note about 'vim'.\n'"
=> A note about vim.   # The ' are ignored.

alias helpx='printf "A note about \'vim\'.\n"' # Invalid syntax

alias helpx='printf "A note about \"vim\".\n"'
=> A note about "vim".   # Some progress, I can now get " here
```

How can I get `'` characters inside my notes in the above?

Comment: it's not about `printf`. it's about nested quoting. it'd be much easier if you define `helpx` as a function.

Comment: I agree that a function would be easier overall thanks. It's odd how close aliases and functions are in bash, they are virtually interchangeable in functionality, not much to differentiate them.

Comment: `man bash` says *"The rules concerning the definition and use of aliases are somewhat confusing. [...] For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions."*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try:

```
alias helpx='printf "A note about '\''vim'\''.\n"'
```

or:

```
alias helpx="printf \"A note about 'vim'.\\n\""
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that the second structure is best for my needs as I feel it is the easiest to read overall, but I see that both ways work perfectly. 

Answer (score 1):

You can do following to escape character while using `printf`-command on an unix terminal:

```
 printf "A note about \'vim\'.\n"
```

Since you are interested in assigning this command to a variale (your alias "helpx"), you could do it at least in two different ways:

- If you have affinity to **ASCI punctuation & symbols**, then without dealing to much with escaping of characters, then use the above solution

  ```
  alias helpx='printf "A note about \u0027vim\u0027.\u000A"'
  ```
- If you don't have affinity to ASCI punctuation & symbols

  use the answer proposed by @tshiono

Hopefully, this will help also in the future when dealing with such problems.

Comment: The use of the ASCI punctuation & symbols is very interesting, something that I've noted for future use thanks.

Comment: @YorSubs, yes right, you're welcome, then feel free to update the answer.